# "contraband" as an uncountable noun

Tags: word-usage, uncountable-nouns

The word "contraband" is defined as follows and marked uncountable in a dictionary:

> goods that are illegally taken into or out of a country

If so, is the following sentence okay?

> This firearm is rare contraband.

Comment: I would say that "this firearm is a rare contraband weapon".

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't normally get used like that to describe a single item. It is used to refer uncountably to it things that are not specifically identified.

> Police seized contraband worth $1 million, including a rare firearm.

In your situation you would probably say:

> This rare firearm was illegally imported.

Comment: Some people say "This firearm is rare contraband" is okay. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's actually OK; perhaps a bit unusual, but not wrong.

It expresses two aspects of the weapon in one sentence: 1) It is rare and 2) It is contraband.  I think it also mildly implies that the weapon is only available as contraband.